# Yii2 CheckboxColumn

Tags: php, yii2

Agrege un checkbox en las columnas del datagrid para poder eliminar varios registros juntos, funciona todo bien. Lo que busco es que al seleccionar las filas a borrar se pinten de un color. Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?. 
Estoy trabajando con Yii2.
Gracias.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'grid',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'layout' => '{items}{pager}{summary}',
        'pager' => [
            'options' => ['class' => 'pagination float-right'], // clase para el elemento <ul> de la paginacion
            'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'page-link'], // clase para los links <a href> de la paginacion
            'linkContainerOptions' => ['class' => 'page-item'], //clase para los elementos <li> de la paginacion
            'disabledListItemSubTagOptions' => ['class' => 'page-link'], // clase para los span que tienen flechas
        ],
        'columns' => [
            [ 
                'class' => \common\components\CheckboxColumnCustom::className () ,
                'content' => function($model) {
                    return  Html::checkBox ( 'selection[]' , false , [ 'id' => "customCheck" . $model->id, 'value' => $model->id] ) . '<label for="customCheck' . $model->id . '"></label>';
                } ,
                'contentOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return [
                        'class' => 'md-checkbox' ,
                    ];
                } ,
                'headerOptions' => ['class'=>'md-checkbox'],
                'header' => Html::checkBox ( 'selection_all' , false , [ 'id' => 'customCheck', 'class' => 'select-on-check-all' ] ) . '<label for="customCheck" class="header"></label>'   
            ] ,
            'tela',
            'descripcion',
            'nom_proveedor',
            'composicion',            
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => Helper::filterActionColumn('{view} {delete}'),
                'buttons' => [
                    'delete' => function ($url) {
                        return Html::a("<button class='btn btn-danger p-2'><i class='fa fa-trash text-center'></i></button>", $url, [
                            'title' => 'Eliminar',
                            'class' => 'delete',
                        ]);
                    }, //fin delete
                    'view' => function ($url) {
                        return Html::a(Yii::t('yii', "<button class='btn btn-warning p-2'><i class='fas fa-palette text-center'></i></button>"), $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Colores'),
                            'class' => 'view',
                        ]);
                    }, //fin view
                ] // fin buttons
            ],
        ],
    ]); 
    ?>
```

Comment: pon el código que estás utilizando

Comment: puedes hacerlo con css y javascript tambien

Comment: Ese es el codigo que tengo en el datagrid, como dije antes, el checkbox funciona y todo. Pero quisiera saber como detectar que checkbox estoy seleccionando para pintar esa fila, si hay alguna forma de hacerlo desde las opciones del mismo datagrid o hacerlo con jquery de otra forma.

Comment: entonces básicamente lo que quieres es  pintar la columna al momento de seleccionar el checkbox o pintar las columnas que ya tengan el checkbox pintado?

Comment: Quiero que se pinten a medida que selecciono los checks, digamos que para visualizar mejor la filas que estoy apunto de eliminar.

Comment: Como dice @danit con javascript es la solución

Comment: Pude solucionarlo, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto lo puedes resolver en el view donde tienes el GridView.

Solo tienes que agregar el código JavaScript o jQuery para controlar los checkbox cuando cambian.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$script = <<<JS
$(function(){
    var checks = $("input[type='checkbox']"); // Obtengo todos los checkbox

    checks.change(function(){
        var trObject = $(this).parent().parent(); // tr que contiene el check
        var check = $(this); // check
        if(check.prop('checked')){
            trObject.css({background:'red'});
        }else{
            trObject.css({background:'none'});
        }
    });
});
JS;

$this->registerJs($script); // Registro el script javascript en el view 
?>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Lo voy a probar, muchas gracias!.